# Famous (cluttered) UI fails that greatly improved

Tags: gui-design

I'm working on a presentation to motivate cleaning up the UI. To get rid of information that might be "nice to have" but is not relevant for everyday use. (Those typical features people brag with, but never actually use).

I'm searching for a famous UI design that was really cluttered and overfilled with information and that either improved greatly in an iteration or has a rival product that is way easier to use.

I'd like to use this for a "before / after" comparison to maybe get some laughter and make the audience relate to it to get them on my side.

Any ideas for good examples?

Comment: I don't have any example, but this SvN article might help: https://signalvnoise.com/posts/3047-the-obvious-the-easy-and-the-possible Or how to have at least 3 levels in your UI, and de-clutter depending on the use frequency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found that Google improved significantly in their interfaces in the last couple of years. The [initial blog post](http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2011/06/evolving-google-design-and-experience.html) by Chris Wiggins compares screenshots of the Google home page in 1997, and 2011.

I'm not aware of any in-depth analyses, but I know that the GMail mobile app also got a major overhaul when compared to its initial web-based mobile version. At the same time, the desktop version of GMail also saw a significant redesign. You can read a detailed account of GMail's evolution over the past decade in [this Time magazine article](http://techland.time.com/2013/05/14/gmail-at-nine-the-evolution-of/) (includes screenshots and video).

For some background information on how Larry Page prioritized Google's design revolution, have a look at [this article](http://www.theverge.com/2013/1/24/3904134/google-redesign-how-larry-page-engineered-beautiful-revolution).

Some example images:

[image: Original Google home page]

[image: Redesigned Google home page]

[image: Original GMail desktop interface]

[image: Redesigned GMail desktop interface]

Comment: Thanks, this is a really useful example for UI that had really unneccessary functionality "right in the users face".

Answer (score 1):

## What about Microsoft Internet Explorer?

It improved tremendously between version 1 and version 11...

### Microsoft Internet Explorer 1

[image: Microsoft Internet Explorer 1]

### Microsoft Internet Explorer 11

[image: Microsoft Internet Explorer 11]

Comment: Not exclusive to IE, as other browsers have followed suit, but I'd argue the removing of standard menu options has made for a more frustrating UI on these newest browser releases.

Comment: @DA01 Oh, I totally agree that it's fustrating. Even Firefox is going that way now (or perhaps I should say Mozilla Chrome???).

Comment: which is actually a good question in itself: why are all of these browser companies blatantly mimicking each other rather than trying to differentiate?

Comment: @DA01 I've just asked. :) See https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/53233/41780

Answer (score 1):

## Microsoft (Office) Word

*In my opinion, the GUI for Microsoft Office Word 2013 is far worse than it was in Microsoft Word 6.*

## Microsoft Word 6

[image: Microsoft Word 6]

## Microsoft Office Word 2013

[image: Microsoft Office Word 2013]

Comment: While there are clear improvements, it should be noted that the 'ribbon' implementation was one of the more poorly handled major UI changes in recent history. (We can argue whether it's better or not, but the actual roll-out caused a lot of inefficient upgrades)

Comment: @DA01 I totally agree on that, too. I'd say that the "Ribbon" is *somewhat* better, but Word 6 was a lot simpler and easier to use than Word 2013.

Comment: That's not a good example. The new GUI is still difficult to use (especially the ribbons). The better overall look is mostly caused by OS changes (e.g. old simple 3d button and scrollbar look, compared to much lighter ones in new OS versions).

Comment: @MikeLischke I never said it was better. I'll quote from my answer: **'In my opinion, the GUI for Microsoft Office Word 2013 is far worse than it was in Microsoft Word 6.'**.

Answer (score 1):

Does the UI look cluttered, or is it hard to use?  The two may be related or they may not. Comparing two screens based purely on look can be risky - especially if hiding elements.

Having said that this blog (http://www.brandonwalkin.com/blog/2009/08/10/managing-ui-complexity/)  not only provides UI comparisons - but also useful categories for analysing different types of visual design complexity

Comment: I'm searching for cluttered UI. Unneccessary, distracting information. But you are right, distraction doesn't have to mean the UI is harder to use, it might just mean it's less time efficient for new users.